# Setting a value in a class is not working

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a class called monetary

```
public class Monetary
{
    double value;
    String type;

    public Monetary()
    {
        value = 0;
        type = "";
    }

    public double getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(double x)
    {
        x = this.value;
    }
```

and i was testing get and set methods so i made a testing class as the following

```
    public class test 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        double test = 5000;

        Monetary testM = new Monetary();

        testM.setValue(5000);

        System.out.println(testM.getValue());


    }
}
```

The problem is that the result java prints is not 5000.0, but 0. I don't get why this is happening. Aren't these methods correct?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `setValue` method:

```
public void setValue(double x) {
    x = this.value;
}
```

You're assigning the parameter the current value of the attribute, it should be backwards:

```
public void setValue(double x) {
    this.value = x;
}
```

Note that even doing this, you will get an output like `5000.0000000...`. In order to fix the result you can use [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) or [`System.out.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", testM.getValue()));
```

or

```
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", testM.getValue());
```

Comment: Wow a stupid mistake, pretty embarrassed right now DX. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are assigning the `value` to parameter `x`, it should be opposite.

```
public void setValue(double x){
    this.value = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void setValue(double x)
{
    this.value = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setValue(double x){
        this.value = x;
}
```

You are assigning the parameter you've passed `x` with the default value of the `value`. You must be doing the exact opposite of that. Assign the `value` with the value passed `x`.

Hence, instead of this `this.value = 5000`, this is happening `x = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the parameter (double x) the value of int value which does nothing because you are return value, so what you want to do is

```
public class Monetary
{
double value;
String type;

public Monetary()
{
    value = 0;
    type = "";
}

public double getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public void setValue(double x)
{
    value = x;//change this
}
```